# How to change working directory in visual studio for Intel MKL

Tags: visual-studio, intel-mkl

I got this error

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB6003 The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: The working directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2023.1.0\bin\ia32" does not exist."

But I found ia32 in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.4.0\bin\ia32"

How can I make the visual studio use the second work directory? By far, my work directory is where my source code located, which is not related to the Intel file

Comment: But I found ia32 in C:\*\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.4.0\bin\ia32"
>> It seems you are using an older version of 32-bit Intel MKL. 

To download a 32-bit version of Intel MKL, please follow the below guidelines.

 1. Use the below link to download 32-bit MKL for Windows.
  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-.download.html
2. Select the Operating system and Distribution.
3. Scroll down for Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit for Windows (32 bit) which includes 32-bit libraries of:
4. Click on the corresponding "Get it now" option which suits your requirement.